# Java code to force all devices to show test ads

Tags: java, android, sdk, admob

```
AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { 
    AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR, // Android emulator 
    "E83D20734F72FB3108F104ABC0FFC738", // My T-Mobile G1 Test Phone 
}
```

I wanted to give my test Android app out to 5-10 of my friends.
Several of these people live 1000 miles away, so there's no way to "use DDMS" or "hook their phone up to my development machine".

I need it to *ALWAYS* just display AdMob test ads.

(It's currently showing REAL ads.)

I don't know (or want to know) everyone's "device ID codes".

I don't want to have to hard-code each 1 into my app.

(And add all new ones all the time.)

Is there java code that will say "whatever device is using this app, is a test device, so just display test ads"?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to add test device on the fly:

```
AdManager.addTestDevice(Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "android_id"))); 
// or Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID if no context available
```

(I didn't test this code.)

Edit:

Decompiling AdMob JAR library gives:

*AdRequest.java*:

```
public boolean isTestDevice(Context context)
  {
    if (this.i != null)
    {
      if ((
        context = AdUtil.a(context)) == null)
      {
        return false;
      }

      if (this.i.contains(context)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Looking at *AdUtil.a*:

```
public static String a(Context paramContext)
  {
    if (c == null)
    {
      if (((
        paramContext = Settings.Secure.getString(paramContext.getContentResolver(), "android_id")) == null) || 
        (c()))
        paramContext = a("emulator");
      else {
        paramContext = a(paramContext);
      }

      if (paramContext == null) {
        return null;
      }

      c = paramContext.toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    }

    return c;
  }
```

Code is obfuscated but we clearly see that it is testing `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` against the value(s) you gave in `AdManager.addTestDevice`.

Comment: I'll try that.  But does AdMob need the "device id", or an "encrypted device id?"

Comment: The context method returns a long alpha/numerical string.  The Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID just returns "android_id" itself.  Neither 1 is the needed "device id" required in addTestDevice to work.

Comment: @Carol `import android.provider.Settings.Secure; Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `AdRequest.setTestDevices` method.

```
AdRequest.setTestDevices( new String[] { 
    AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR, // Android emulator 
   "E83D20734F72FB3108F104ABC0FFC738", // My T-Mobile G1 Test Phone 
});
```

You are likely looking at old AdMob documentation from before the Google AdMob SDK rewrite.

There is no way to say you want test ads on all devices.  This is a precautionary measure so that you can't accidentally release an app that serves all test ads to everyone.

Comment: So how do I get all those "magic numbers" from 20 different test devices... many that are 1000 miles from here?  (The individual beta testers are never going to want to install eclipse, and the SDKs, and java, and set up a full developer environment just to get that 1 number.)

Comment: The easiest way I know how is to have them install an app that spits out logs.  I use `aLogcat`.  If they install that app and go into your app into the activity where you make an ad request, they can then go back into aLogcat and find the line in the logs that says something like `To get test ads on this device, call AdRequest.addTestDevice("E83D20734F72FB3108F104ABC0FFC738");`

Answer (score 0):

I disable the advertising system completely in test builds, and only enable it for local debug builds on devices I own.
You could show a static image in place of the advert so you can still have the same layout.